# Change value of a segmented control?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

How do i change the value of a segmented control through code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
UISegmentedControl *cont;
.....
cont.selectedSegmentIndex = 4; //Selected index you want;
```

Comment: note that this also causes the segmented control to send a message to the target, which you might not expect

Answer (score 5):

```
[segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:(NSInteger)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the segment control value by using property `selectedSegmentIndex`

For Ex. `segmentedControlObject.selectedSegmentIndex=1;`

For Tutorial you can refer [this](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-segmented-controluisegmentedcontrol-tutorial/)